# Trouble with DTO in MVC C# possible casting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, union, dto

I am getting this error everytime i try to write a method that excludes the serivce already possessed by a user.  So i have two list, List1 which is all services and List2 which is a list of all services possessed by a user.  So i am doing a Union exclude on the two lists but evertime i try to com

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' C:..\Controllers\ServicesController.cs

```
private List<ServiceDTO> getList(ServDTO.ServDTO[] services, IEnumerable<string> servObtained)
{
    var allServices = servicesClient.GetallServices();
    var allServicesCode = (from s in allServices select s.serviceCode).ToList();
    IEnumerable<String> list1 = allServicesCode;
    IEnumerable<String> list2 = servObtained;
    var listFinal = list1.Union(list2);
    List<ServiceDTO> list = listFinal.ToList();

    return (list);
}
```

Can anyone shed some light onto why im running into this issue??

Comment: you are turning ``List<string>`` and assigning it to ``List<DTO>`` which is obviuosly wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are returning wrong type, change you code to return right type. Compiler does not know how to convert `string` to `ServiceDTO` you have to do it yourself.

Change these two lines:

```
List<ServiceDTO> list = listFinal.ToList();
return (list);
```

with:

```
 return listFinal.Select(x=>new ServiceDTO(){serviceCode = x})ToList();
```

to return `List<ServiceDTO>` back, currently you are returning `List<string>` while your method return type is `List<ServiceDTO>`